# How to solve this ODE system with an implied integration within it?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this system of differential equations in time, which I am trying to solve numerically through a matlab code:

$$
\frac{df(x,t)}{dt} = K(t) -Af(x,t) - B\sigma \left[C f(x,t)g(x,t)+\frac{(1-C)}{D^2}\int_0^\infty x'e^{\frac{-x'}{D^2}}f(x,t)g(x,t)dx'\right]$$
$$
\frac{dg(x,t)}{dt} = \beta Af(x,t) + B\sigma f(x,t)g(x,t) - \frac{B}{x}g(x,t)
$$
Where A, B, $\beta$, $\sigma$, C and D are known constants. I also know K(t) time dependency is gaussian.

I have no idea how to solve this, as I have no information about neiter $f(x,t)$ nor $g(x,t).$ The only thing I know is that both are $0$ at $t=0$ and at $x=0$. I don't want the solution to the problem, just possible ways to solve it numerically.

Comment: Have you ever heard of finite element methods? It is very powerful for solving ODE's numerically; especially using MATLAB. Here is a good resource: https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/finite-element-method

Comment: This equation.... :o even me, the mighty nose of Riemann finds this insane